# Func<> with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have found following part of code in some examples while learning **Func<>** syntax:

```
  public static class Lambda
    {
        public static int MyFunc(Func<string, int> func)
        {
            //some logic
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**And sample call :**

```
var getInt = Lambda.MyFunc((url) => { Console.WriteLine(url); return 0; }
```

**And My Question :**

Why passing above func as lambda expression with this (url) is allowed if value is never assigned ( or maybe is ?)?
What is the point of passing Func like this ?

**Edit :**
To clarify my question  . I was only wondering about this sample call - why passing string as argument like above (using lambda (url) => {} ) is not forbidden by compiler if the value can not be initiated. Is there any example that can be useful with passing string like above ?

Comment: The way you have it written, it doesn't do anything unless you call the func in your `MyFunc` method...

Comment: I think whatever is going on in //Some logic may be important here

Comment: Radek, please consider editing you post to match Jon's answer if he answered to what you are looking for. Otherwise in current form you post is very unclear as one really can pass whatever object (including null) if the value is not used at all.

Answer (score 10):

`url` is the name of the *parameter* for the lambda expression. It's like writing a method like this:

```
public static int Foo(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine(url);
    return 0;
}
```

Then creating a delegate from it:

```
Func<string, int> func = Foo;
```

Now in order to *call* the delegate, you need to provide it a string - and that then becomes the value of the parameter, just like if you called the method normally:

```
int result = func("some url");
```